# Unit Test Description question

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

There is a description entry for Unit Tests in Visual Studio. Is it possible to modify a test description after creation?

Comment: At runtime, or just at any time?

Comment: @Tarynn, welcome to SO. If you are talking about the comments of the Test description then yes. If you could please show some code that might make your questions a bit clearer.

Comment: Please don't add things like "Visual Studio, C#," to your titles. That's what we use tags for on [SO].

Comment: @John Saunders sorry this was my first post, I won't do it again

Comment: @Jethro I'm not sure how to show code to represent this problem as it is more a visual studio problem but I will try to provide steps that will make my question more clear...

1. Open Test view window
2.Right click and select add/remove columns
3. Add description column

At this point all my description columns are blank because I didn't use the wizard to create the unit test, I'm trying to figure out if there is an edit option somewhere (I haven't found one yet) or if there is a way to add the metadata in the code

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 [TestMethod]
 [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Description("Test Case Description")]
 public void EnsureTestCaseValid()
 {      
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

The Description column in the Test View is readonly, but if you select a test and look in the Properties window, you'll find that the Description property is editable. This will add a `[Description("string")]` attribute to the test.

Comment: I've seen this mentioned in a bunch of different places, but I've never managed to see a test method in a property grid. Where does one need to go to see that?

Comment: It's no longer there in VS2012. Earlier, I think you should look in the Test View, off of the "Test->Windows" menu.

Comment: This is just crazy. The other time I've seen this mentioned was to setup a datasource on the gui. Setting up a datasource by hand on the attribute requires one to go to the docummentation to see the format of the connection strings and such. Is there really no alternative to this anymore in VS2012+ (this might even be another question entirely... I'll just post it right now)?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409112/how-do-i-change-unit-test-properties-through-the-ui-in-the-newer-versions-of-vs) it is.